# SQL Server account disabled even in single user mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm integrating with a third-party product via its SQL Server 2008 R2 database. In a previous version, I was able to access the database via SQL Server Management Studio and SQLCMD as a Windows administrator using Windows authentication.

The third-party product controls the sa account and keeps the password a secret.

After applying the vendor's latest product update, I can no longer access the database using Windows authentication. I even tried single mode, but no luck.

Here's how I switched to single mode:

```
net stop MSSQL$FOOBAR
net start MSSQL$FOOBAR -mSQLCMD
```

That seems to start the database.

```
C:\>sqlcmd /S .\FOOBAR
Msg 18470, Level 14, State 1, Server WINMAC\FOOBAR, Line 1
Login failed for user 'WINMAC\steve'. Reason: The account is disabled.
```

Is there a way in? Or is it more likely the vendor has closed a hole and I can't get in?

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PSExec to connect to an instance using the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/

However bear in mind that you may be breaking some contract, just wanted to note it :)

Original author is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475970/recover-sa-password)

Comment: Thanks. Not to worry about contracts. I don't have a relationship with the vendor (yet), just their customers. Interestingly, once I got in, I realised I no longer needed to make the previously required modifications because the vendor realized the error of their ways, which means I don't have to deploy PsExec to customers. Yay!

Comment: I'm able to access master with this method, but when I go to create a new server level login i get a "User does not have permission to perform this action".  Any ideas on what else I can do? I need to access a separate database on my machine that I'm getting blocked from.